# NextJS SSR and CSR Combination Possible?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I would like to know if it is possible for a product detail page to be Server Side Rendered only if user opens [www.site.com/product/id](http://www.site.com/product/id) page directly but Client Side Rendered when user opens the page from another page via `<Link>` .e.g they open [www.site.com](http://www.site.com) then navigate to [www.site.com/product/id](http://www.site.com/product/id) by clicking on a`<Link>`, this page should no longer get SSR but CSR instead. Is that possible?

Comment: I don't think so, there is this feature known as ["Shallow Routing"](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing), but it doesn't work across pages. If you have a [`getServerSiderProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#server-side-rendering), then even if you are navigating to that page (from other page) using [`next/link`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link), the [data fetching](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching) method will run.

Comment: this was possible though using older reactjs right? using middleware ?

Comment: When using `getServerSideProps` the page will _not_ be server-side rendered on client-side page transitions. It will simply run `getServerSideProps` on the server and return the results as JSON to be used to render the page on the client. See [`getServerSideProps` docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#only-runs-on-server-side) for details.